# Question about leetcode 217: Contains Duplicate

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, hashtable

I'm doing the leetcode question #217 : Contains Duplicate.
After checking the answer, I cannot understand some parts of the code. The question is as given below:

```
Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1]
Output: true

Example 2:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: false
```

The answer is the following:

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
            if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                return True
        return False
```

The following is my question:

In my understanding, looping through `range(0,len(nums)-1)` allows us to check and compare characters in `num[0:-2]`, but what about the last two characters?
How can we compare those two characters if we have `nums` like `[2,14,18,22,22]`.
And for the last two lines, why can't we directly use `return False` instead of using the `if...else...` structure?
How is the logic been written here?

Thanks for anyone who can clarify my puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

You *are* comparing the last two elements. When `i == len(nums)-2`, you compare `nums[i]` with `nums[i+1]`. Those are the last two elements.

You don't need `if/else`. As soon as you find a duplicate, you immediately return from the function. So the only way to get to the end of the loop is if there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**Python Solution:**

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        return len(set(nums)) != len(nums)
```

set() method in python takes parameters like Any iterable sequence like list, tuple, or dictionary and returns an empty set if no element is passed. Non-repeating element iterable modified as passed as argument.

Here, we are checking if the length of the list after iterating equals the length before? If yes implies there is no number repeated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`range(start, end, step` function work from `start, start+1, start+2 ... end-1`, where end is exclusive and start is inclusive.
ie for `range(0,100,1)` it wil go as `0,1,2,3,4,5......96,97,98,99`.

if your code you are checking character ith and(i+1)th character. so in at last index `ie (len(num)-2)`, you are checking `len(num)-2` and `len(num)-1` character which include the last elements.

now why return directly `false`. it is considering that all element are distinct if the program is reached till this statement. if any duplicate is found then it will be found in the for loop.